# Canon 6D Mark-ii + Kenko C-AF 1.4x Teleplus pro 300 + Kenko 1.4x teleplus HD shows Error

Tags: lens, canon, canon-5d-mark-ii

I have a Canon 6d mark-ii camera. However, the kenko lens are not working and yesterday, I tried to fix my camera with a friend. They had the same camera and lens but those are working with mark-ii model.

If anybody help me to get solution canon 6d mark ii + kenko 1.4x dgx or HD now working shows Error 01 always even after cleaning and purchasing the newer one.

Comment: Which lens are you using with the converter? Is the lens working without it? Have you cleaned the contacts?

Comment: I use 50mm Canon with Kenko teleplus HD,the both lens works with my other canon 6d Camera. Yes this is brand new lens but both are not working with mark-ii model. 

Very starange issue for me !!! any idea?

Comment: I purchase a new kenko and 50mm also today but unfortunelty both are not working with canon 6d mark-ii model. 

I updated latest firmware from canon website also, but still it wont.

Comment: I sadly don’t. I just tried combining my 5d mark ii with the kenko pro 300 1.4x and canon ef 50mm 1.8 mark ii and it worked even if it hunted quite a bit for focus.

Comment: If you update the firmware of your older EOS 6D, the Kenko will probably throw the same error code on it that it does on your newer 6D Mark II.

Comment: Dear Lijat,

Thank you so much for your prompt reply, we do not use canon 5dmark-ii model. We use canon 6d mark-ii model with kenko and 50mm that throws error code 01. Now there is no issue with 5d i agree but their is an issue with canon 6d mark-ii. 

Any thing i can do to run the kenko ON canon 6d mark-ii model?

Comment: Dear Michael C If i update canon 6d firmware older version in somehow canon 6d mark-ii model then is it works?

anything i can do to run the kenko teleplus lens in canon 6d mark-ii?

Nor canon Nor Kenko are replying this issue, please help. .....

Comment: You can't run a 6D Mark II using firmware written for the 6D. If you try it will probably brick the camera. You can *try* to load the oldest version of the 6D Mark II firmware if you can find it anywhere (Canon usually only makes the latest firmware for each camera available for download). But there's a good chance the camera will refuse to go backwards to an older firmware than the one currently installed.

Comment: You're probably out of luck. Your most likely solution is to use a Canon EF 1.4X instead of a Kenko. You never know what version you're getting with Kenko TCs. You could buy one "new" today that has been sitting in a retailer's inventory since 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Autofocus Microadjustment (AFMA) (see page 200 of the [EOS 6D MkII Instruction Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004270/02/eos5dmkii-im5-c-en.pdf), or [5D MkII manual](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300027469/05/eos6d-mk2-im4-en.pdf)).

If AFMA is enabled, even if the adjustment for the particular lens/TC combo mounted is "0", some Kenko TCs will lock up the camera. This still occurs even if the lens is set to 'Manual Focus'. It's been fairly well discussed in certain forums.

I've got an older Kenko C-AF 2X Teleplus Pro 300 DGX bought in 2011 and all of my cameras from about 2012 on have this issue. With AFMA set to 'Enable' if the shutter button is fully pressed the camera throws an 'Error 01' and locks up the camera. It must then be turned off with the battery removed to reset the camera. With AFMA set to 'Disable' there is no 'Error 01' when using the teleconverter.

Comment: i tried by disabling the AFMA but still it throws the error code 1.nor rnable nor disable work for me... any update?

Comment: @MishraAditya Turning off AFMA is what worked for me with a 5D Mark III, A 7D Mark II, and a 5D Mark IV. Other than that, you could try the [tape trick](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27599/15871).