# Can the Sigma 2x teleconverter be hacked so it will work with the Sigma 50-500mm?

Tags: canon, autofocus, sigma, teleconverter

Does the [autofocus hack](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/is-it-important-that-the-canon-1dx-isnt-specified-to-autofocus-with-lenses-slow/17056#17056) (where you mask off connectors on the teleconverter to make it misreport the aperture) work on sigma 2x teleconverter fitted on Sigma 50-500mm DG lens for Canon cameras?

Answer (score 3):

The hack itself will always work, but the reliability of the autofocus suffers. The lens you're asking about is a f/6,3 in the long end and with a 2x teleconverter the autofocus will probably be painfully bad if working at all.

I've used the sigma 1.4x teleconverter (connectors masked) on the same lens and even that struggles autofocusing on bodies that are specified at f/5.6 autofocus.

Comment: Hi Hugo,
Do you have any images taken using a similar set up? If yes, could you post a link to the sample images?

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately I don't since it didn't work out very well and all of my glass is fast nowadays. Even if I had any pictures saved they would all be sharp since the out of focus ones would have been thrown away.